# Last line of the last reference has wrong indentation

Tags: bibtex

I have a journal of class:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
```

and the bibtex reference at the end:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{vldbj_references}

\flushend

\end{document}
```

but the last reference[59], no matter which one it is, always has the last line with wrong indentation as in the attached photo:

[image]

No matter what changes I make to the reference in the bibtex file or if I select another reference. The last line will have incorrect indentation.

Any idea why this happening?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the column balancing has collected and examined the last line on the page using `\lastbox`, and in doing so it has lost the horizontal offset (lists use `\parshape`).

What is the `\flushend` command? I guess it comes from the flushend package. Looking at the package documentation I see an obvious package option:

**keeplastbox** It skips removing anything from the last column. As example it is useful and can be used then document ends by reference item and last line of text should be with indent.

That is, if a balanced page may end with a bib-item, or any type of item, then you should use

```
\usepackage[keeplastbox]{flushend}
```

If you aren't using the package directly, but it is being loaded by the mysterious svjour3 class, you might be able to do

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,keeplastbox]{svjour3}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! \usepackage[keeplastbox]{flushend} fixed it. I was already using the package flushend directly so I just added the option keeplastbox